# For Loops not running inside If statement Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a code to update an inventory spreadsheet on the first of every month. I have very little knowledge of VBA but I understand the basics of programming. Please excuse my poor code.

The problem is that after the initial If statement check, when true it only runs the line directly below it (adding a new line) and does not execute the For Loops after it to edit the data.

```
Sub Auto_Open()
Dim stock(21)



If Date - Day(Date) + 1 = Date Then

Range("'Monthly Office Inventory'!A2").EntireRow.Insert

For i = 0 To 21
stock(i) = Range("Current Office Inventory'!A2").Offset(0, i).value
Next i

For x = 0 To 21
Range("'Monthly Office Inventory'!B14").Offset(0, x).value = stock(x)
Next x

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `does not execute the For Loops` - why do you think so? code works for me. Also I suggest you to use `Worksheets("Current Office Inventory").Range("A2")...` instead - it's more natural way

Comment: It adds the new line but all cells remain blank. It was working before I added the Newline

Comment: you should check whether you really have any data in `'Current Office Inventory'!A2:V2`

Comment: Im sure i have data there, and I apologize for poor coding. I've been copy pasting the stuff i need to make it work. It was printing out the data just fine, but on the bottom line. i thought it would be easier to just add a new line and always print it on the top instead of trying to make a more dynamic script to print on the bottom line.

Comment: I found my problem. Sorry, it was a simple mistake. I forgot to change the location of where it was printing to the top line @.@ I was printing down inside my old data. Thanks for the help

Comment: try to use this line `Worksheets("Monthly Office Inventory").Range("B14:W14").Value = Worksheets("Current Office Inventory").Range("A2:V2").Value` instead your loops

Comment: man, that seems so much more efficient

Comment: yeah, and easy to read code:)

Comment: New favorite code site!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use this line Worksheets("Monthly Office Inventory").Range("B14:W14").Value = Worksheets("Current Office Inventory").Range("A2:V2").Value instead your loops

@simoco

https://stackoverflow.com/users/3067523/simoco

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do this will be changing you condition to:

`If Day(Date) = 1 Then`

Now, I'm writting this on a Mac, but I think you'll get the idea (and correct it if some detail is wrong).

Comment: I was using `If Date - Day(Date) + 1 = Date - Day(Date) + 1 Then` to test

Comment: It was just printing to the wrong location. Problem solved. My bad. Thanks

Comment: Then I'll try to use something like `If Day(Date) = 6 Then` (6 for today), because adding a Date and an integer (`Day(Date) + 1`) probably will not work. There's a function for that `DateAdd()` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcxe65wz(v=vs.90).aspx so this probably means it won't work.

Comment: No the date function was working fine. I was using it to take today's date, then find the first day of the current month with it. then it would check to see if today's date was the same as the first of the month. that ran smoothly